# Retrieve the multiple values in dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have two column in database table one is country and other is port.At the time of insertion selecting the country from dropdown related port is loaded in listbox.
Then we selecting the multiple port for one country and insert in to database.

```
Eg.  Country:-India Port:-AGARTALA,BAGDOGRA,BANGALORE,COIMBATORE
```

The table view is like this. Now i need to retrieve all ports which is inserted in table in dropdown list one by one.How to Solve...Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What part of this question do you need help with?

Comment: now i already add 5 countries and ports related  that countries now i have five rows of ports name with multiple ports separated with comma now i need to load that all ports in dropdown

Comment: Got it.  So there are 3 parts to this:  Querying the database, loading data into objects in .NET, and finally, returning the data through to the client.  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: how to separate that text by comma and load in dropdown using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to split your data:

```
var data = 'Country:-India Port:-AGARTALA,BAGDOGRA,BANGALORE,COIMBATORE';

var portStart = data.lastIndexOf('-')+1;

//create an array of items by removing the garbage in the beginning
//and splitting on the commas
var ports = data.substr(portStart).split(',');
```

Then use jquery's `$.each()` method to iterate over all the items in the array:

```
// ports -> the array from above
// function()...  the operation to perform on each item in the array
$.each(ports, function (index, value) {
    //insert an option element into #ports with the value/text attributes set as shown
    $('#ports').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
});
```

Comment: but how to add all record in data from database

Comment: Your question needs work and this isn't a free code service.  This is more than enough for you to at least go try it yourself.